# Python datetime.strptime - Converting month in String format to Digit

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a string that contains the date in this format:
`full_date = "May.02.1982"`

I want to use datetime.strptime() to display the date in all digits like: "1982-05-02"

Here's what I tried:

```
full_date1 = datetime.strptime(full_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

When I try to print this, I get garbage values like `built-in-67732`
Where am I going wrong? Does the strptime() method not accept string values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format string is wrong, it should be this:

```
In [65]:

full_date = "May.02.1982"
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.strptime(full_date, '%b.%d.%Y')
Out[65]:
datetime.datetime(1982, 5, 2, 0, 0)
```

You then need to call `strftime` on a datetime object to get the string format you desire:

```
In [67]:

dt.datetime.strptime(full_date, '%b.%d.%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[67]:
'1982-05-02'
```

`strptime` is for creating a datetime format from a string, not to reformat a string to another datetime string.

So you need to create a datetime object using `strptime`, then call `strftime` to create a string from the datetime object.

The datetime format strings can be found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) as well as an explanation of `strptime` and `strftime`

Comment: I suggest to add a list of directives for operating with datetime: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior